# Stripe Payment Issue - Expo - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjcw9.png)
[CalculatedPrice on Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDht1.png)

Hey guys, I'm reaching out about a payment stripe issue I have. I'm trying to use JSON to parse a value I'm calculating on frontend to the stripe backend server code. I'm unsure on how I could import that data.

This is the code that stripe uses to render the amount of money the user has to pay. I would love to use that "amount" variable and replace it with the payment the user selected on the UI instead. I'm unsure on how I should go about using the backend stripe server code to get this value from my frontend code.

Any help is welcome -- I'm a newbie to stripe, so I'm trying my best. Thanks for the kindness!

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 87,
    currency: "usd",
    customer: customer.id

  res.json({
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
    customer: customer.id
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.